# Selecting and Grouping a set of points in a 2D plane

Tags: geometry, algorithms, graph-theory, pattern-recognition

I am currently working on a project that requires to solve the following problem:

Let's say that each time a user access a specific resource on the network from his mobile device, a system stores his position (latitude, longitude).

Then I need to be able to tell the user the "areas" from which he use to access that resource. And by "areas" y could mean circumferences (center & ratio).

The problem is I need some criteria to **discard isolated points** and I need some criteria for **grouping remaining points** into "areas".

I bet there must be some literature on the subject, but the issue is I dont even know the terms to refer this problem, and where to start looking.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know much about the geometric aspect of the problem but in general, there is a good algorithm for detecting statistical outliers called the BACON algorithm that is implemented in most software packages, I hope that helps.

Comment: Ok I've been researching a bit, and it looks like BACON algorithm has a very wide target, but my problem certainly has a lot to do with outliers detection.
So thanks.